# How do I properly add an onchange attribute to a form field in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, drupal-forms, drupal-render

In the module I am coding, I have this code:

```
        'SelectType' => array(
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#name' => 'dropdown',
          '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(
                        'Keyword-classic','Keyword-Encore','Reserves: Instructor',)),
          '#attributes' => array('id' => array('SelectType'),
                  'onchange' => "change_action('catalogsearch', this.selectedIndex)",
          ),
        ),
```

This produces this result:

```
[...]
<select id="SelectType" 
    onchange="change_action(&#039;catalogsearch&#039;, this.selectedIndex)"
    name="dropdown" class="form-select">
[...]
```

I need it to produce (outputting ' instead of ' on the third line) :

```
[...]
<select id="SelectType" style="float:left;" 
    onchange="change_action('catalogsearch', this.selectedIndex)"
    name="dropdown" class="form-select">
[...]
```

What do I need to change to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the "Drupal" way of doing this.

Step 1, set a variable to contain dropdown by using drupal_add_js:

```
drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => array('varname' => 'catalogsearch')), 'setting');
```

Step 2, add the 'onchange' line as

```
'onchange' => 'change_action(Drupal.settings.mymodule.varname, this.selectedIndex)'
```

By doing this, the variable is passed without the need of `'` to be passed through the theme system.  The theme system always calls `check_plain` on attribute values, therefore `'` or `\'` is always converted to `&#039;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
    'SelectType' => array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#name' => 'dropdown',
      '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(
                    'Keyword-classic','Keyword-Encore','Reserves: Instructor',)),
      '#attributes' => array('id' => array('SelectType'),
              'onchange' => 'change_action(\'catalogsearch\', this.selectedIndex)',
      ),
    ),
```

And by the way, as `ID` is unique and only one can be use at a time to an element, you should use `'id' => 'SelectType'` instead of `'id' => array('SelectType')`.

**Edit:**

If the above code doesn't work then you can use `jQuery` like following:

```
$("#SelectType").change(function() { 
    YOUR CODE.....
});
```

Comment: Thank you for a prompt answer.  
Unfortunately, I tried using the \' and got the same result.

Comment: ,Your updated answer had the same problem...drupal does not like passing quoted values inside an onchange.  This is why you have to set the variable via drupal_add_js and then use the variable in your js.